# Azure Resource Manager .NET SDK, copying VHDs/Blobs

Tags: .net, azure, azure-blob-storage, vhd

I am trying to find a way to copy a VHD to my storage account in my resource group.

I have a Sas Uri of a VHD.

I Powershell I would use:

```
Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy `
-AbsoluteUri $sas.AccessSAS `
-DestContainer 'vhds' -DestContext $destContext -DestBlob 'MyDestinationBlobName.vhd'
```

to do that.

I can't seem to find a way to do it from .NET SDK of Azure Resource Manager.
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/AutoRest/src/ResourceManagement/

Is there any way I can copy a blob using .NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way I can copy a blob using .NET?

You would need to use `Azure Storage SDK for .Net` ([`Github`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net)|[`Nuget`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/)).

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;

    static void CopyBlobUsingSasExample()
    {
        var destinationAccountName = "";
        var destinationAccountKey = "";
        var destinationAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(destinationAccountName, destinationAccountKey), true);
        var destinationContainerName = "vhds";
        var destinationContainer = destinationAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient().GetContainerReference(destinationContainerName);
        destinationContainer.CreateIfNotExists();
        var destinationBlob = destinationContainer.GetPageBlobReference("MyDestinationBlobName.vhd");
        var sourceBlobSasUri = "";
        destinationBlob.StartCopy(new Uri(sourceBlobSasUri));
        //Since copy operation is async, please wait for the copy operation to finish.
        do
        {
            destinationBlob.FetchAttributes();
            var copyStatus = destinationBlob.CopyState.Status;
            if (copyStatus != CopyStatus.Pending)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);//Sleep for 5 seconds and then fetch attributes to check the copy status.
            }
        } while (true);
    }
```